# Can we use Activiti to detect any problems in running application

Tags: spring, activiti

I'm quite new to the Activiti. I have a Spring Application which I would be running in Tomcat7 as a WAR file. I want a mechanism to report any crashes/exceptions/failures in the process (as checking logs is a burden and I would like to automate the process and get notified with a mail or something in case of failure).

Can Activiti help me in finding those ?
If not, can you direct me to something which does that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Create a Process which starts with a Message Start Event and contains a mail task. Create a rest api in spring which triggers this workflow. Whenever a severe exception occurs this process is triggered via rest call (request body may contain details regarding the exception). and the user will receive a proper formatted e-mail regarding the exception form the other application. Please keep in mind the frequency of exception that can occur.

hope it helped...